# How can I extract the value of a variable using simple algebra when the max function is involved?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, programming

I have a C program that does the following calculation:

```
int b = 16;    
int a = max(1, ( (b + 3) / 4 ) ) * max(1, ( (b + 3) / 4 ) ) * 16;
```

More easily read as:
$$ a = \max\left(1, \frac{b + 3}{4}\right)^2 × 16 $$

I would like to know how I could use simple algebra in order to find what is the equivalent algorithm to find the value of `b` if I am only given the value of `a`? For example:

```
int a = 256;
int b = ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To say it another way, the range of the function on the RHS is $a \ge 16$ (plot $a$ against $b$ if you don't see it.) There are three cases:

- if $a \lt 16$, it is not in the range, so there is no $b$ that can produce that value.
- if $a = 16$, then $\max(1, (b+3)/4) = 1$ and any $b$ where $(b+3)/4 \le 1$ will do.
- if $a \gt 16$ then there is a unique $b = 4\sqrt{a/16} - 3 = \sqrt{a} - 3$ that produces that $a$ (assuming you want the positive square root only).

Comment: Thank you, but then that means that in the case of a = 256, that b would be equal to 61 when I expect b to equal 16. Am I missing something fundamental here?

Comment: Sorry  - missed the squaring of the max result. I'll edit, but the result for b is going to be 13, not 16 - right?

Comment: It should be 16, when I run `int a = max(1, ( (16 + 3) / 4 ) ) * max(1, ( (16 + 3) / 4 ) ) * 16;` I get 256 as a result.

Comment: That's probably because your program is doing integer division (truncating the result to the nearest integer towards 0): under the "normal" interpretation, $ (16+3)/4 = 4.75$, *not* 4, so $ a = 4.75 \times 4.75 \times 16 = 361$, *not* 256.

Comment: Ok this makes perfect sense now, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. This is because there exists more than one possible value for $b$ that returns the same value of $a$. For example,

$$\max\left(1, \frac{-1+3}{4}\right)\cdot 16=\max\left(1, \frac{-2+3}{4}\right)\cdot 16=16.$$

So, if all you know is that $\max\left(1, \frac{b+3}{4}\right) = 1$, you have no way of knowing what $b$ is, since it could be $-1$ or $-2$ or some other number.

---

However, there is still something you **can** extract, if you are given $a$:

**If $a=16$**:

In this case, you know that $\max\left(1, \frac{b+3}{4}\right)=1$, and this happens if and only if $\frac{b+3}{4}\leq 1$ (since, if it were greater than one, then $1$ would not be the maximum). So, in this case, you can conclude (after multiplying the inequality by $4$) that $b\leq 1$.

**If $a\neq 16$**:

In this case, you know for a fact that $16\cdot \frac{b+3}{4} = a$, since $a$ can be either $16$ or $16\cdot \frac{b+3}{4}$, and it isn't $16$. Therefore, you have $4b+3=a$ and you can, in this case, calculate exactly what $b$ is: $b=\frac{a-3}{4}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however to be honest I don't really understand. You're saying that if a is not 16, then it's possible. But I don't understand what the code would translate into in the case of a = 256 (for example). I'm very new to math so I apologize if it's obvious

Comment: @mbl If $a=256$, and $a=\max\left(1, \frac{b+3}{4}\right)$, then what is $\max\left(1, \frac{b+3}{4}\right)$ equal to?

Comment: I think you missed the square (as I did :-)) and there are mistakes in the algebra in the $a \ne 16$ case as well.